# My Toshiba laptop doesn't find the external monitor

Tags: drivers, 13.04, 64-bit, multiple-monitors

Having used Ubuntu 12.04 and still using Mint 14.1 with an additional monitor on my Toshiba, when I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on the same laptop with that same monitor, it doesn't see the monitor.

It displays boot up on the external monitor but once booted will only see and use the laptop display.

The system otherwise works perfectly...

Toshiba Tecra-R10
Processor: **Intel Core 2 Duo CPU P9400 @ 2.4GHz x 2**
Graphics:  **Quadro NVS 150M/PCIe/SSE2**

The graphic driver shows as `Gallium 0.4 on NV98`. That's all I know on the subject.

Comment: any solution yet? I am having the some problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. After you plugin the monitor you must open Displays Setting in System setting.

[image: Displays]

I had the same problem and it will automatically detect my display (TV and external monitor) after I open the Display option in system setting. By the way, I'm using the same driver. Hope it will help you to.

Comment: That's the first thing I did when looking for the monitor, in fact that's the exact image I have when I open the display settings, just the laptop display showing, thanks for your answer though

Comment: Having come to the conclusion that I'm not going to get an answer/solution to correct this issue, I've decided to abandon Ubuntu 13.04 and wait for the next LTS version to move beyond the 12.04 that I use on my primary machine, which works flawlessly...

Comment: In the course of my playing with Zorin Linux 6.3 I had issues with video (similar but not precisely the same ones) and I sought help on their help forums. I got this, among other repository related stuff which made no difference. But this fixed my display issues in Zorin Linux...

http://www.zoringroup.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2490